# Recursive Modelling Function Query

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

(c) Suppose we model the spread of a virus in a certain population as follows. On day 1, one person is infected. On each subsequent day, each infected person gives the cold to two others.

i. Write down a recurrence relation for this model.

ii. This model fails to be realistic since it does not take into account that people get better. Modify your recurrence relation to account for re covery, assuming that the average person takes 8 days to recover from a cold.

I'm confused how to do this question especially part ii)? Your help would be much appreciated. Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Try to write your question directly without linking it as an image.